# Is there any way to have FL Studio load banks, when importing a MIDI File?

Tags: midi, daw, studio

I'm trying to load some MIDI Files into FL Studio that use the Yamaha s yxg50, but when I import a MIDI it leaves the banks blank in every MIDI Out.
That means, I have to manually set them all after I imported them, which is quite a hassle.
The MIDIs do have banks set and a media player in which I loaded the Yamaha VST does play them correctly, so I'm wondering why FL Studio doesn't.
Does anyone know how to set FL Studio up to load them, or perhaps knows another program that let's me do that?

Answer (score 1):

Anything other than very simple patch and controller changes will often be transmitted as MIDI [System Exclusive](http://www.indiana.edu/~emusic/etext/MIDI/chapter3_MIDI9.shtml). Unfortunately FLStudio [does not seem to support SysEx](https://forum.image-line.com/viewtopic.php?t=84967).

There might be a workaround (see [this post](https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=283407)) but it looks rather involved.

Answer (score 0):

it may not be possible in Fl Studio but depending on your keyboard it might be possible to save registrantion of your banks so all you would have to do is select the correct saved registration for a particular file much simpler than manualy loading banks if I understood you correctly. Sorry I do not have exp with Fl studio I use Anvil Studio and it suits my needs quite well.